# GAE users service object - local variable creation or not?

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, optimization

So ... using the Google App Engine User service.

Should I create a **local** user object:

```
my_user = users.get_current_user()
if not my_user:
    self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri), abort=True)
    return
person = Person.get_current(my_user.user_id()) #Here
```

or access the user object from the users service anytime? :

```
my_user = users.get_current_user()
if not my_user:
    self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri), abort=True)
    return
#...  code ...
person = Person.get_current(users.get_current_user().user_id()) #And here
```

or something else? :

```
helping useres :-)
```

and of course why. Is usage of users service costly in resources?

Comment: Sorry for the edit's .... forgot to replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A locally scoped user object should be fine for each request.

Make sure my_user is local to your thread and the current request:

- if it's shared between separate requests, there's no guarantee that it's really the same user issuing the request, unless you have some separate session validation.
- different threads can be handling different request, in which case you run into the above problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Before I get scared, if my_user is inside the request handler in def get() then is it possible to become globally accessible? I might be missing something here. I thought that every request handler has his own thread.

Comment: Every request gets its own thread.  If my_user is inside def get() you're good.  If it's outside and global, you can get problems.

Comment: No usage of course is not global. I would never do that and It would only be really stress tested.

Answer (score 1):

A local call is always better as a call that triggers many method calls. The efficiency gain depends on the frequency your code is calling it. For 2 calls it's okay.